# LayoutInflater Onclick Not working

Tags: android, onclick, layout-inflater

I have 2 xml one main xml and one menu xml. I want to get the click event from menu xml to main xml activity. is there is any way to solve this problem.

Main Home Page

[image: Main Home Page]

Menu Page[image]

Now click on the menu page button event i want in my main home activity page.

I done Like this

```
    View otherLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout,null);

    Button tstclick = (Button) otherLayout.findViewById(R.id.textclick);        
    tstclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Your thing

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: okay, at first show your work

Comment: View otherLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout,null);
  
  Button tstclick = (Button) otherLayout.findViewById(R.id.textclick);  
  tstclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          //Your thing
      
       System.exit(0);
      }
  });

Comment: do you want menu item in toolbar?

Comment: Its a Slidingmenu.

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` class provides us two methods to inflate/show menu items and work with them or assign some tasks to them. They are:

1. onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
2. onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

The `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method is responsible for creating and inflating the menu by help of `MenuInflater` class.

The `onOptionsItemSelected()` method is responsible for assigning tasks to each menu item. Each menu item is identified  by help of its unique ID.

In order to show and work with menu's in any Activity, both the methods needs to be overridden as shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        // All your menu items will come here. Each menu item ID will become a separate case in the Switch case
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
       }
    }

}
```

As soon as the user clicks or taps on any menu item, the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method is called by the Android OS and then the ID for that particular menu item will be matched in the method. The group of statements specified in the respective case will then be executed.

For more info visit the following links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html

Comment: I am useing Sliding menu

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that.